# OpenCL: increase maximum number of pipe arguments

Tags: pipe, opencl

I have a design composed of several kernels communicated via pipes.

One of my kernels has more than 20 pipes, but the limitation on a Intel i5 CPU seems to be 16:

```
# clinfo | grep pipe
Max number of pipe args                         16
Max active pipe reservations                    65535
Max pipe packet size                            1024
```

Question: is there any way to increase number of pipes args?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd do this: Producer writes data pipe, also saves indexes (20 of them) into command pipe. Consumer reads command pipe, extracts 20 id values and does 20 x reads on data pipe. If all 20 datas can fit into single packet, why not make 1 struct to hold all data? Are those pipes completely decoupled from each other or have different number of reads/writes? Maybe you can achieve same thing using a "any" type design to hold any data type at a time but not all and do 20x reads/writes again. Maybe having an extra "type" field in struct and a float, int, userDefined1, userDefined20, .. near that field.

Comment: `struct myType { int typeId; float data1; int data2; float4 data20; }` but I don't know if type based code branching and using a big struct is slower or faster.

Comment: @huseyin why not type all your comments into an answer then?

Comment: @Matthieu its not what L30nardo SV. asks. Just a workaround.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik too bad, because it looks good (at least better than "buy a new CPU" ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and yes.

No, because this is a descriptive information related to your hardware.
That line is the output [of the following code](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo/blob/9d3f66f603d1e76173ed42be1d9181c991fb4226/src/clinfo.c):

```
{ CLINFO_BOTH, DINFO(CL_DEVICE_MAX_PIPE_ARGS, "Max number of pipe args", int), dev_is_20 },
```

CL_DEVICE_MAX_PIPE_ARGS seams to be a new feature of opencl 2.0 [New in version 2015.2.](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime_const.html?highlight=pipe#device_info.MAX_PIPE_ARGS)

This is the same like how many cores you have.

If you have only 2 cpu cores you hardly using 8.

Yes, because there is a way to increase number of pipes args.
You Have to buy an other CPU one which supports more arguments.

My answer is probably disappointing.
Sorry
Good luck with your project.